# Excel Search Index and Trim Matched Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to search for a row and return only part of the text in the row

[image]

I'm using this formula

`=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("LineItem #",B16),INDEX($B19:$B34,MATCH("*"&"Thermal Requirement"&"*",$B19:$B34,0))),"")`

which returns the full row. Is there a way to pick out part of the row. for example just pull `U-Factor = 0.35` from the row.

I know I can do this with a helper column but I am wanting to do it all in the same column if possible.

Comment: Search for "U-factor" and use MID formula?

Comment: As SJR alludes to, your formula return the whole cell string, you will need to further process the returned string.  Note that if your version of Excel supports Dynamic Arrays your formula can be greatly simplified using Filter

Comment: @luke when posting sample data please post it as Text, so we can copy paste it for testing.  If you think adding an image adds value, you can post that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a version of Excel that supports Dynamic Arrays, you could use a combination of `Filter` and `FilterXML` instead of your `Index` formula, to filter out only the U-Factor bits

Formula in `E17` (Spills to `E17:E18` for this sample data)

````
=FILTERXML("<h><a>"&SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B19:B30,LEFT(B19:B30,19)="Thermal Requirement"),",","</a><a>")&"</a></h>","//a[contains(text(),""U-Factor"")]")```
````

or put the search terms in seperate cells

```
=FILTERXML("<h><a>"&SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B19:B30,LEFT(B19:B30,LEN(E9))=E9),",","</a><a>")&"</a></h>","//a[contains(text(),""" & E10 & """)]")
```

[image]

Note that if there are more than 1 "Thermal Requirement" line in the data range, this will Spill

---

### How it work

Broken done and refering to the below image:

The inner `Filter` returns a Spill range of just "Thermal Requirement" lines

```
=FILTER(B19:B30,LEFT(B19:B30,LEN(E9))=E9)
```

This Spill range is then formatted as XML

```
="<h><a>"&SUBSTITUTE(G17#,",","</a><a>")&"</a></h>"
```

The XML is then filtered to return the "U-Factor" nodes

```
=FILTERXML(H17#,"//a[contains(text(),""" & E10 & """)]")
```

[image]